# Is this a valid proof of $0 < a < b$ implies $a^n < b^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Using induction. Assume $a^k < b^k$. Multiply both sides by $ab$. $ba^{k+1} < ab^{k+1}$. Divide by $b$. $a^{k+1} < (\frac{a}{b})b^{k+1}$. Since $a < b$, $\frac{a}{b} < 1$. Therefore $a^{k+1} < (\frac{a}{b})b^{k+1} < b^{k+1}$

Comment: Proof no good, because you did not say whether $a,b$ are positive.  Instead of saying "multiply both sides by $ab$," site the result you use that lets you multiply inequalities.

Comment: 1) What is the context? (where are $a,b$ living?) 2) Why multiply by $ab$ and then divide by $b$ (instead of just multiplying by $a$)

Answer (score -2):

If nothing is mentioned then this statement is not true.
Look at
take a=-1,b=0 then -1<0
But taking n=2 we have (-1)^2<0 [ According to your result ]
that is 1<0 which is absurd.

In your proof you have used three main step

1. Multiply both side by ab
2. divide by b
3. a/b<1

For these steps we must have the condition 0<a<b

Also since you want to use mathematical induction so n should be natural number.